# Rsyslog imfile permission denied

Tags: jenkins, logging, permissions, rsyslog

I'm trying to use rsyslog imfile to send logs contained in Jenkins log files to a Graylog server, I added root user to jenkins group but I've still permissions issues when rsyslog tries to read files.

Here is the rsyslog script :

```
module(load="imfile")
ruleset(name="infiles") {
    action(type="omfwd"
    target="graylog.server"
    protocol="tcp" port="1514" )
}
input(type="imfile" tag="jenkinsJobs"
file="/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/*/builds/*/log")
```

And I get the following error :

`imfile: poll_tree cannot stat file '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test/builds/legacyIds' - ignored: Permission denied [v8.1901.0]`

I also tried to let user jenkins execute the script but he can't send back logs to rsyslog, since he hasn't the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Check for selinux context using ls -lZ on target file. You can disable selinux if not required.